# Best approach for loading dependent select fields in page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having some difficulty on settling on an approach for loading additional data in an application that I am building. For example I am having two drop-downs in my page Country and state. My approach is when user select a state I make ajax call and loads related state. But The different approach which I am thinking about is I should load all the states at ones and using `JQuery` show only those states which belong to the country selected by user and hide others. Is it right approach or ajax call is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience both solutions are good. All will depends of your goal and of the context of usage of your application.

If this dropdown is used in a process such as a registration and will be therefore be **used by your visitor only one time**, then you will surely not mind using some asynchronous loading of data (ajax). But you will have to keep in mind that the **UX** should remain good. So don't hesitate to add a spinner or things like that to show that it's "loading".

At the opposite, if this dropdown will be **used multiple times** in the same session, then you are definitely looking not to block your user each time he wants to use this. So you will probably load your data in the DOM/js.

In your example (list of country/states), if it's not an heavy amount of data, then you should definitely load it initially. If at the opposite the amount of data you are looking to load is huge, best would be to do it asynchronously after the initial loading of your page (in ajax).